# Image not loading when Passing Typed array

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, android-viewpager, typed-arrays

**I am using a custom viewpager adapter. I need the viewpagers at multipleplaces so I made a constructor to accept the TypedArrays.
But the problem lies that the image isn't appearing. The number of viewpagers are correct(4 in my case) but it is all white**

arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <integer-array name="your_array_name">
        <item>@drawable/apple</item>
        <item>@drawable/apple</item>
        <item>@drawable/apple</item>
        <item>@drawable/apple</item>
    </integer-array>


</resources>
```

**customViewpager**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private TypedArray GalImages;

    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    ImageAdapter(Context context, TypedArray imgarray){
        this.context=context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        GalImages=imgarray.    //I don't understand what to write here
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return GalImages.length();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages.getResourceId(position,0));

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}
```

**Calling Adapter**

```
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        Resources r = getResources();
        TypedArray imgarray = r.obtainTypedArray(R.array.your_array_name);
        final ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this,imgarray);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

**Thing is if I make an integer array of drawable ids in the image adapter itself, then it works fine, but I need different arrays for 2 viewpagers and I surely don;t want to make an adapter for that too**

Comment: Add code how are you calling `ImageAdapter`? Also make sure `ViewPager` is visible in layout .

Comment: @ADM I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks is Ok. It should work . Use constructor as follows. And make sure `ViewPager` is visible in layout.

```
 ImageAdapter(Context context, TypedArray imgarray){
        this.context=context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        GalImages=imgarray;  
    }
```